# Devise's validateable module doesn't respect custom defined email_required? method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise

So far as I can tell, in order to use the validateable module, but selectively disable the email field's validations, you must define a protected method email_required? on your model and have it return false.

I've done this, but it appears the email validation is still triggered. Is this a bug in devise, or am I missing a crucial step?

Below are the relevant parts of my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    protected
      def email_required?
        false 
      end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still running into this, it has been added--but I believe only in the 1.2 branch.  Download and install the 1.2rc and you can skip email validation as done in the question.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, the feature was documented but not implemented in version prior to 1.2?

Comment: That's the way it looks.  I looked in the earlier branches and they all had the old code.